# Add button to a dynamically created table row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

so Iam trying to add this button to a dynamically created table row. But I honestly don't know how to get this working. The code is a mess, because Iam trying so many things in order to get this going.

I need to append this button (element) to the table row where the function is called, is there any smart way to do this. If i change my structure of the table, thats okay.

```
function getPerson(){
//addButton.value = "+";
//addButton.class = "btn btn-success";
$("#output1 tbody tr").remove();
fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {

        console.log(data);

        var temp = "";
        data.forEach((person) => {
            temp += "<tr>";
            temp += "<td>" +person.id+"</td>";
            console.log(person.id);
            temp += "<td>" +person.vorname+"</td>";
            temp += "<td>" +person.nachname+"</td>";
            temp += "<td>"
            person.projectList.forEach((project) => {
              temp += project.name+"<br>";
            });
            temp += "</td>"

            temp += "<td>"
            person.technoList.forEach((techno) => {
              temp += techno.name+"<br>";
            });
            temp += "</td>"




            temp += "<td id='addButton" + x + "' >" + addButton(person.id)+ "</td>"
             //this.parentElement.appendChild(this)
             x++;


            //document.getElementById('personDetail_Button').addEventListener('click', this.personDetail(person.id));
            temp += "</tr>"


        });

        document.getElementById("tableOutput").innerHTML= temp;

    });
}

function addButton(person_id){
  var person_id_onclick = person_id
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.type = 'button';
  element.value = 'test123';
  element.onclick = function(){
    personDetail(person_id_onclick);
  }
  $(element).addClass('btn btn-primary');
  //$(this).appendChild(element);
  document.body.appendChild(element);

}
```

```
<table class="table" id="output1">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Vorname</th>
                <th scope="col">Nachname</th>
                <th scope="col">Projekte</th>
                <th scope="col">Technologien</th>
                <th scope="col">Button</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tableOutput">

        </tbody>

    </table>
```

Comment: in the dynamically created row there is nothing attached to your addbutton(person.id) call.  i would do it like this <td onclick='addButton("+person.id")' class....  > </td> Also why are you adding "x" to the addbutton id in the same row, use person.id since its already there and it is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try replacing `document.body.appendChild(element);` with `return element;` I also updated the function to remove the random jquery class.

```js
function addButton(person_id){
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.type = 'button';
  element.value = 'test123';
  element.setAttribute("data-person_id",person_id);
  element.setAttribute("class","btn-viewdetail btn btn-primary");
  
  var _wrap = document.createElement("div");
  _wrap.appendChild(element);

 return _wrap.innerHTML;

}

var _btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-viewdetail");
_btns.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener("click",function(evt){
    personDetail(evt.target.getAttribute("data-person_id"));
  });
});

document.body.innerHTML += addButton(4);
```

Comment: That worked! But now Iam stuck with this "[object HTMLInputElement]". Because it dosen't have a parent Element i cant append a Child.

Comment: @Gerrit I updated my code so it creates a div that the element gets appended to then returns the innerhtml of that div

Comment: Thanks. That worked too. But with this change the onClick function can' be triggered anymore. Any ideas one this problem?

Comment: @Gerrit I forgot about the appending order bug with event handlers. I have updated my code to REMOVE your click handler, and replace it with a single handler at the bottom that gets a data attribute with the person ID that is also added in my updated function.

Comment: I just tested your code. The querySelector picks up your test button, but not my dynamically created ones. The query selector is at the end of the js file. I've posted my code in jsfiddle. I would be create if you would have another look at it. https://jsfiddle.net/wg0rueat/1/